# Limit Proof Question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

How to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x)}{\lim_{n\to\infty}g(x)}=\frac{L}{M}$ if g(x) is not equal to 0 using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition. I know the proof that uses the idea of $\frac{1}{g(x)}$ and the uses multiplication rule of limit, but I am wondering if there is a direct and more elegant proof.

Comment: This proof is pretty direct, especially considering that division cannot be defined without a prior definition of multiplication (algebraically speaking). What do you have in mind exactly?

Comment: You  say "g(x) is not equal to 0" but you do **not** say that M, the limit of g(x), is not 0.  That is separate and necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Well, suppose both $f$ and $g$ converge ($g$ to something nonzero). Then we can make them as close to their limits as possible, so the difference $$\left|{f(x)\over g(x)}-{L\over M}\right|=\left|\frac{Mf(x)-Lg(x)}{Mg(x)}\right|=\left|\frac{M(f(x)-L)-L(g(x)-M)}{Mg(x)}\right|$$ can be made small by taking f and g sufficiently close to L and M, and by ensuring that g is far enough away from zero.